# How to find general solution of PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

How to find general solution of equation 
$$
U_{xy}- \frac{U_x}{y} =0 ?
$$

My approach:
$$
U_{xy} = \frac{U_x}{y}.
$$
Integrate w.r.t $x$
$$
y \ U_y = U + c
$$
integrate w.r.t y

I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Remember the constant of integration can be a function of $y$ Also. Can't really point you any further without some conditions. With the conditions you then have a first order ode in y.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Chinny84, the integration constant $c$ should be a function of $y$. Then you get the equation
$$
U_y=\frac{1}{y}\,U+C(y),
$$
where $C(y)=c(y)/y$. This is a first order linear equation. Solving it and renaming the "constants" of integration, the general solution of the PDE is
$$
U=\psi(x)\,y+\phi(y).
$$

Comment: Doing a search of my name on MSE (self-indulgent I know) but I saw this answer :) which deserved a +1. I also hate it when OP do not accept!